# string column conversion to float in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: pandas, string, dataframe, integer

I want to get left value (LD) pipe separated value from the DataFrame column "'CA Distance Nominal (LD | au)" here is the code.
when I convert the string to float I get all the values as NaN.

```
cneos = pd.read_csv('cneos.csv')
print(cneos['CA Distance Nominal (LD | au)'].head())
cneos['Distance']=pd.to_numeric(cneos['CA Distance Nominal (LD | au)'], errors='coerce')
print(cneos['Distance'].head())
```

**Result**

```
0    2.02 | 0.00520
1    0.39 | 0.00100
2    8.98 | 0.02307
3    3.88 | 0.00996
4    4.84 | 0.01244
Name: CA Distance Nominal (LD | au), dtype: object
```

**After to_numeric()**

```
0   NaN
1   NaN
2   NaN
3   NaN
4   NaN
Name: Distance, dtype: float64
```

How can I get the both values LD and AU separated in float

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure that it is the best way to resolve your problem, but it works:

```
separeted_data_frame = pd.DataFrame(cneos['CA Distance Nominal (LD | au)'].apply(lambda x: x.split('|')).to_list())
separeted_data_frame.columns = ['LD', 'AU']
separeted_data_frame.LD = separeted_data_frame.LD.astype(float)
separeted_data_frame.AU = separeted_data_frame.AU.astype(float)
cneos = cneos.join(separeted_data_frame).drop('CA Distance Nominal (LD | au)', 1)
```

The result is:

```
    LD  AU
0   2.02    0.00520
1   0.39    0.00100
2   8.98    0.02307
3   3.88    0.00996
4   4.84    0.01244
```

Is it what you wanted?

Comment: that works and it added two new columns with 'LD' and 'AU' names that can I modify. thanks